# Continuous function maps $F_{\sigma}$ sets to $F_{\sigma}$ sets

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove if $X\subset \Bbb{R}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ (can be written as a countable union of closed sets) and $f$ is continuous then $f(X)$ is $F_{\sigma}$.

**Proof:** Let $X=\cup C_i$ where $C_i$ is closed. Then define $D_{i,n}=C_i \cap [-n,n]$. Then $D_{i,n}$ is compact (closed because intersection of two closed sets, and bounded by $n$). Note that $X=\cup D_{i,n}$. Because $f$ is continuous, it maps compact sets to compact sets. So $f(X)=\cup f( D_{i,n})$ which is a countable union of closed sets.

Does this look okay? This is a [previous qualifying exam question](http://www.math.purdue.edu/files/academic/grad/qualexams/MA54400/MA544-jan16.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks fine to me. You should get full marks for that.